# Theme seems to be permanently changed

Tags: themes, colors

I added this to my init.el:

```
  ;; Transparent Emacs   
  ;;(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(<active> [<inactive>]))
    (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(88 70))
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 88 70))
```

Which make the background of emacs transparent. However when I removed this code from the init.el, the change persists. Why?

Comment: Are you using desktop mode? (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) or a customisation file? It's possible that theme-related settings are finding their way into the persisted state that those packages save.

Comment: @StuartHickinbottom: I'm betting that's the answer (desktop). If confirmed, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Do you compile your init files by chance?

Comment: @Drew -- will do. As the question was a bit open-ended I didn't want to speculate too early!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using:

```
(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(100))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 100))
```

The `alpha` parameter specifies the opacity of the frame, the second argument specifies the opacity when not full screen.

Instead of using the above transparency setting which will persist I added these to init.el and call with M-x when needed.

```
(defun transparency-on ()
  (interactive)
  "Sets the transparency of the frame window. 0=transparent/100=opaque"
  (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha 70))

(defun transparency-off ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha 100))
```